# How to create a cell that overlaps another?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to create a cell with the total size of the existing col, and this cell will be on top of the nearest cell.

The purpose of this is to create a kind of percentage graph.

Example:

[image]

I've already tried for absolute position in tr, or in td, however, the width 100% is never equal to the width of the table, it always exceeds it.

Comment: That is not something appropriate for a cell to do. Try adding another layer with `background-image` or whatever under the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting task to do.

I did it using HTML and CSS. You can use javascript as well.

[image]

In the following solution width is static, but you can pass dynamic width,

I hope you will have your own width calculation logic, or either you can convert it into a percentage and increase-decrease bar width accordingly.

here is the link to Sandbox solution https://codesandbox.io/s/table-showing-percentage-2ovpec?file=/src/index.js

Comment: If the table is fluid with width 100%, how would you dynamically calculate the percentage values ​​in conjunction with the insertion of colors? Because if I enter 100 in width, the color will only take one column, when in fact it should take all columns, since 100% percentage is everything?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS as you said it will only occupy that column, you can give more percentage if you want to overlap with another column, give width: 130%, this percentage obviously you need calculate. Example, suppose the price of one pencil is $1 but due to inflation, it gets to $ 2.5 so in this case % increase in price is now 150% more, similarly for your width calculation you need to do this

Comment: In our case, to cover all the tds, it would be a width of 266%, which would correspond to 100%, how can we dynamically calculate this?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS sure can help, would you please share which value depicts percentage in your case? I can add it in sandbox then.